# Select different objects from two collections

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```cs
struct UserRecord
{
    //--- common settings
    int               login;                      // login
    int               leverage;                   // leverage
    int               enable;                     // enable
}
```

And I have two lists:

```cs
List<UserRecord> base_data = new List<UserRecord>();

base_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 1, leverage = 1000, enable = 0});
base_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 2, leverage = 100, enable = 0});
base_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 3, leverage = 10, enable = 1});
base_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 4, leverage = 10000, enable = 0});

List<UserRecord> snapshot_data= new List<UserRecord>();

snapshot_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 1, leverage = 1000, enable = 1});
snapshot_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 2, leverage = 100, enable = 0});
snapshot_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 3, leverage = 10, enable = 1});
snapshot_data.Add(new UserRecord(){login = 4, leverage = 10000, enable = 1});
```

My goal is to filter the records, and get the two records in a new list, that are with different fields, in this case only the field 'enable' is different.

```cs
var filtered_data = new List<UserRecord>(); // here records with login 1 and 4 should go.
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may look for [`Enumerable.Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0) from *System.Linq* to find the differences between both enumerable.

```cs
using System.Linq;

List<UserRecord> filter_data = base_data.Except(snapshot_data)
            .ToList();
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JknpTO)

---

Another approach is if you just want to compare the difference in `enable` based on the items with the same `login` and `leverage` from the different lists.

You need to **join** both lists by the key(s) and query the record from the first list with the different `enable` value.

```cs
List<UserRecord> filter_data = (from a in base_data
                                join b in snapshot_data on new { a.login, a.leverage } equals new { b.login, b.leverage }
                                where a.enable != b.enable
                                select a
                                ).ToList();
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MJBiKM)

Comment: So except will compare all fields ?

Comment: @pewocis495 *by using the default equality comparer to compare values.* , but there is an overload to provide your own equality comparer if needed. See the documentation.

Comment: @pewocis495 "So except will compare all fields ?", if you look at the fiddle apparently it compares it fields

Comment: @pewocis495 is the first approach not you want? The except behavior is credit to what Natrium mentioned, compare with the default Equality Comparer, check the object from first list with all the fields whether it is in the second list. Or probably you may look for the join.